# Как отследить готовность элемента на странице?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте!

По нажатию кнопки дублирую контент из textarea в div.

Как мне отследить готовность элемента div (момент когда все в него загружено)?

Делаю так:

```
// само копирование
document.getElementById('temp-content').innerHTML = document.getElementById('content').value;

// попытка отследить окончание загрузки
document.getElementById('temp-content').addEventListener("load", function() {
  alert('Все загружено!');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать "наблюдателя" ([MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)). Свойство `childList` указывает на то, что необходимо отслеживать добавление или удаление дочерних элементов и текстовых узлов.

```js
const MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;
const observer = new MutationObserver((mutations) => {
    console.log(mutations[0].addedNodes);
});

const target = document.getElementById('temp-content');
observer.observe(target, {
    childList: true
});


setTimeout(() => {
    target.innerHTML = '<span>SPAN</span><div>DIV</div><a href="#">A</a>';
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div id="temp-content"></div>
```